# How do I export my WordPress blog as a book?

Tags: export, pdf

I want to export some or all of the posts of a blog into a format that makes sense to a publisher (traditional or self-publisher(e.g.: [Lulu.com](http://www.lulu.com/))) (MS Word, RTF, PDF, epub, something else).

What tools are available to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Anthologize

A great option is the [Anthologize](http://anthologize.org/) plugin.  It works with WordPress 3.0, allows you to format your book in WordPress itself, and then publish everything automatically to PDF, ePub, and other formats.

Comment: This plugin crashed for me while trying to export a large blog (12 years of posts). Blogbooker worked great, though.

Answer (score 3):

[Blogbooker](http://www.blogbooker.com/wordpress.php) is a service which takes an XML export of your blog and turns it into a PDF, which could then be uploaded to a self publishing platform.

Comment: Actually up for me.

Answer (score 1):

Also - check out PressBooks ... http://pressbooks.com/

I've used it for one of my ebooks and it's great ... also does Kindle and Nook file formats.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Can you at least explain what the service is capable of doing and how it integrates into WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You can export into XML. and Using XML as the base, you can develop your scripts/workflow to use the XML and convert them into various formats that you would want to.

Comment: That's pretty vague. What kind of transforms would I need to do to get it into the standard formats I mentioned?

Comment: unfortunately the XML export does not work when e.g. you have 10.000+ posts...

Answer (score 0):

Try the new WP plugin Blog TO PDF: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blogtopdf/

Comment: Erik, given that the Avatar is the same, I assume you are the author of the plugin, please check the [faq] on how to proceed in this case. ::: Seems interesting, will give it a try. ::: I [saw](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/blogtopdf/tags/1.0.0/blogtopdf.php) that you are using the `save_post` hook without checking for auto-save, Ajax or a security Nonce, research here for working examples of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Papyrus http://papyruseditor.com/en/blog2book

It fetches the blog contents using the rss feed of your blogs, and converts it into an ebook in PDF,Epub and Kindle(Mobi) formats

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an offline solution and keep track of your data and articles, you could try [Wordpress2Doc](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/08/31/wordpress2doc-how-to-convert-wordpress-articles-into-word-and-pdf-documents/).