# Export whole wordpress blog to PDF or similar including images

Tags: pdf, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I export my WordPress blog as a book?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-do-i-export-my-wordpress-blog-as-a-book)

I would like to know how can one export all the posts content to a PDF file or Word or similar that includes all the pictures.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used a site called blogbooker.com once to pdf my whole site..... it worked pretty well

Comment: unfortunately it did not work for me; images do not apper on the PDF

Comment: No kidding? It worked for me, images and all. Sorry it didn't work for you

Comment: no, unfortunatelly no kidding my dear friend

Comment: @gpu_drug "did not work for me" is no proper description for a problem.